# child class object in unable to run overridden method instead parent class method is being run both times

Tags: java, methods, interface, overriding

new to programming...just trying to understand method overriding.
In the following code, object from child class which  overrides Parents class method, but still with child class object I can't run overridden method (m()).
I set return type different-- float in parent and double in child, if the particular method is not overridden due to that then child class also implements the same method from interface u and still not running overridden method..

```
class Parent {
public float m(float m){ 
    System.out.println(" parent class with float return");
    return m;
}}
class Child extends Parent implements u {
    @Override
    public double m(double y) { /*method name same - Parent class & interface
different return type */
        System.out.println(" child class with double");
        return y;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child child = new Child();
       child.m(10);/*child object running parent method*/
       Parent g = new Child();
     g.m(10);
    }
}
interface u  {double m(double y);}
```

Comment: The method name AND parameter list form a unique identifier.  So `m(float)` is different from `m(double)`.  Java is also taking `10` and automatically applying a conversation, in this case to support `float` over `double`.  You can convert the value using `child.m(10d);` which will cause the `Child`s `m` method to be called instead

Comment: thanks, I got it now..it goes like highest is int-long-float-double..

Comment: thanks, I got it now..it goes like highest is int-long-float-double...can you suggest some good book to understand   Java compiler JVM rules

Comment: You could try looking over the [java jvm specifications](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+jvm+specification&client=safari&rls=en&sxsrf=AOaemvI5UNu3Td_bXhHBlu9C5FOFM9Xnwg%3A1641868956019&ei=nO7cYaBOgcDctQ-X37ioCg&gs_ssp=eJzj4tFP1zc0NK4yTk82Tzdg9BLLSixLVMgqy1UoLkhNzkzLTE4syczPAwDfKgyn&oq=java+jvm+sp&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMYADIFCC4QgAQyBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB46BwgAEEcQsAM6BwgAELADEEM6BAgAEEM6CggAEIAEEIcCEBQ6BQgAEIAESgQIQRgASgQIRhgAUNQFWLQQYOwgaAJwAngAgAGeAYgB2QSSAQMwLjSYAQCgAQHIAQrAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to override a method called `m` which returns a `double` which doesn't exist in the parent class, the parent class has a method `m` with a return type of `float`, these are different. Basically the current `@Override` doesn't actually override anything since a method with that name and return type doesn't exist in the parent.

You fulfil the interface contract because a method `m` exists which returns a double.

The reason why you get the same output is because you are calling the `Parent` classes `m` function because of the type of argument you are passing in (10 is being determined as a float). If instead you call the function with a double, i.e 10d then the `Child` classes m method will be called.

Change your main method to the following and it will now call the parent and child methods:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child child = new Child();
        child.m(10.0);/*child object running parent method*/
        Parent g = new Child();
        g.m(10);
    }
```

Comment: *niggle* I'd use `10d` instead of `10.0` as it's "generally" clearer as to your intention, just saying 